# Python resource for remote sensing?

Tags: python, remote-sensing

I am looking for a good resource (MOOC, book, etc..) to teach Python for remote sensing applications.  I am already familiar with http://www.rsgislib.org/ - are there any other resource out there for a beginning Python programmer?

Comment: You might consider [machine vision](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-801-machine-vision-fall-2004/) courses as an indirect way to gain relevant technical knowledge

Comment: What is MOOC? Could you edit your Question to write it out in full before abbreviating, or include a link to a definition, please?  Also, you are essentially asking for a shopping list which is a category of question which I think should be asked only with care: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3483/should-shopping-list-questions-be-off-topic-and-closed-on-gis-stack-exchange

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Form the (i)python basis to the more complex manipulation:

[Dr M. Disney - Introduction to image data handling](http://www2.geog.ucl.ac.uk/%7Emdisney/teaching/3051/hdf_prac/)

These two blog have many examples:

[Luca Congedo  - From GIS to Remote Sensing](http://fromgistors.blogspot.it/2013/09/integrate-python-script-that-clips.html)

<s>[REMOTESENSING.IO](http://blog.remotesensing.io/2014/04/counting-atolls-of-the-maldives/#more)</s> [web.archive.org:RemoteSensing.io](https://web.archive.org/web/20200219174533/http://blog.remotesensing.io/2014/04/counting-atolls-of-the-maldives/)

Things became more interesting with more spectral bands:
http://www.spectralpython.net/

Another book about this topic:

[Image Analysis, Classification and Change Detection in Remote Sensing: With Algorithms for Envi/Idl and Python  by
Morton J. Canty](http://www.amazon.it/Analysis-Classification-Change-Detection-Sensing/dp/1466570377/ref=sr_1_1?s=english-books&ie=UTF8&qid=1397832905&sr=1-1&keywords=python+remote+sensing)

Answer (score 8):

Utah State University has an excellent class with online resources titled [Geoprocessing with Python using Open Source GIS](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/).  You will find tutorials on common RS methods such as digital image processing using edge detection algorithms and calculating NDVI from ASTER imagery.  Additionally, there is a downloadable [zipfile with presentation, scripts, and data](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/).

Answer (score 4):

If you're using RSGISLib you might find the MSc Python course taught at Aberystwyth useful. The notes and example scripts are available to download from here:

https://bitbucket.org/petebunting/python-tutorial-for-spatial-data-processing/

They start with basic Python then get into Remote Sensing applications.

Answer (score -4):

Here is free python course, http://grindgis.com/blog/free-python-course-for-gis-users-from-coursera-org.

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality as it is essentially a link-only answer. These types of questions are often most succinctly answered by a link, but it would improve the quality if you could give a summary/description of the course and why it might be more useful/helpful than another. Bonus points for tying it directly to remote sensing as the original question asks.